# How to pass data from React to Alan-AI Studio?

Tags: reactjs

I am asking for a country from a dropdown from a user. Then I want to pass this country to alan studio so that I can add this country to NEWS_API_URL

Comment: You're asking for a country from a dropdown and we're asking the code that you've written by far. You can post it in a codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: Can I give the link to github repo?

Comment: https://github.com/Naman-2001/News-AI-Chatbot  and this the link to codesandbox with alan studio code:-  https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-sun-bveew?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Your `<Home />` component is receiving the country value

Comment: Yes, but this country is stays in react only.I want this country to be passed to Alan Studio.

Comment: You can make a HTTP request to your Studio? 

Comment: Well I dont know how to do that? If you know please let me know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of how you can send data to the voice script in Alan Studio: `callProjectApi` and `setVisualState`.

You can use `setVisualState` method to pass the current state of the app to the voice script. This can be helpful if you need to know the app state to adjust the logic in the dialog flow, for example, filter out some voice commands, give responses applicable to this state and so on.

The `callProjectApi` method has a more general usage. It can help if you need to pass any data to the voice script or perform some actions (call functions, set variable values) without a voice command.

You can read more info here:
https://alan.app/docs/server-api/visual-state
https://alan.app/docs/server-api/api-reference#projectapi

Comment: Yes, I figured this out.I did it using setVisualState. Thanks for your answer.Do check what I made using Alan here:-https://github.com/Naman-2001/News-AI-Chatbot